# how to add int from a string of array as a attack damage of my card game

Tags: java

I'm working with my school project making a 2 player card game. I'm trying to start making the array of heroes but I don't know where I can store the int for the attack/damage. I'm about to make 100 Heroes and deal randomly to the users each player will have 5 cards.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AngelsAndMinions {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Player 1 Name : ");
        String Player1 = in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Player 2 Name : ");
        String Player2 = in.next();

        String [] Heroes =  new String[5];

        Heroes[0] = "Winter Wyvern - Like many great poets, Auroth just wants time to write, but the Winter Wyvern's life is full of interruptions.";
        Heroes[1] = "Visage - Perched atop the entrance to the Narrow Maze sit the looming shapes of sneering gargoyles, the paths into the hereafter forever in their gaze.";
        Heroes[2] = "Skywrath Mage - A highly placed mage in the court of the Ghastly Eyrie, Dragonus lives a troubled existence. "; 
        Heroes[3] = "Jakiro - Even among magical beasts, a twin-headed dragon is a freak.";     
        Heroes[4] = "Puck - While Puck seems at first glance a mischievous, childish character, this quality masks an alien personality.";
}
```

Comment: Can you make your heroes objects and give them an attack/damage property?

Comment: *"i dont know where i can the int for the attack/damage"* we neither, but... 1) You should follow Java naming conventions, 2) Read about MVC pattern and convert `heroes` to an array of `Hero` class which includes all the hero information, 3) `Player` should be another object containing the `Hero` chosen and the player name... 4) Please take the [tour], go through the [help] and read [ask] to improve your question

Comment: Hey there, Im sorry but i just started java coding , and we are surprised for this project, because we dont have really idea how to get started working with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a class for your hero:

```
public class Hero {

    public String name;
    public String description;
    public int damage;

    public Hero(String name, String description, int damage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.damage = damage;
    }   
}
```

And in your main() method create an array of heroes and create Hero objects:

```
Hero[] heroes =  new Hero[5];
heroes[0] = new Hero("Example Hero", "Example description", 50);
```

Comment: This is what OOP is all about! Programmatic representation of real world objects! :D

Comment: Great answer. I would add an extra attribute `description` :)